# Qt - where to get /opt/qt59/bin/qt59-env.sh?

Tags: qt

I have a project which relies on `/opt/qt59/bin/qt59-env.sh` which sets up QT environment. Without it, `qmake` complains:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick quickwidgets

It's not on my system (Ubuntu 17.10). I have QT 5.9 installed through `qt5-default`. I have been looking around but can't find. I've tried packages `qtscript5-dev` but `qt59-env.sh` did not appear.

What should I install to get it? Or what's an alternative to set up the environment?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's default packages don't include this kind of script.
qt59-env.sh comes from [qt59base](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt59-xenial/+build/13537554), that is from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt59-xenial).
The ppa is for Ubuntu xenial (16.04), but it could also work on 17.10.

Otherwise you can just download qt59-env.sh from [here](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt59-xenial/+build/13537554/+files/qt59base-dbg_5.9.0-1basyskom1_amd64.deb) and modify the paths to your installed Qt version.